# Kendo Combobox - reset value when the selected value is not in the datasource

Tags: user-interface, combobox, kendo-ui

We were using Telerik MVC extensions for ASP.NET MVC and have started migrating to Kendo UI now.

I am facing an issue with Kendo Combo and the details are as follows:

Suppose that I am binding a Kendo combo with a list of ten items (whose values are from 1 to 10 along with a blank item (say "Select" and it's value is "")) and in my markup, if I say .Value("0") - I don't want the kendo combo to show me "0" but instead get reset to the blank item or may be the first item in the list.

How can I achieve this ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your int has to be a nullable type.

ex:

```
public class SomeDTO
{
    public int? ID {get; set;}  //must be type int? and not int
    public string Name {get; set;}
}   


// on your kendo binding, .DataValueField('ID')
```